# Simple Employee Database Program

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a beginner employee database program. 
Here is the problem; when counter "i" in main() becomes "1", the 1st line of the loop is skipped; in the other words, it doesn't wait for user to enter the value for "name" string. When I use "cin" rather than "gets" there is no problem...Why this is so? I use ubuntu 16.04.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
void enter();
void report();
    char name[2][30],salary[2][30];
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        cout<< "Name:"<<'\n';
        gets(name[i]);
        cout<< "Salary:"<<'\n'; cin>>(salary[i]);
    }
    report();
    return 0;
}
void report()
{
        int i;
        cout<<"Name"<<'\t'<<"Salary"<<'\n';
        for(i=0;i<2;i++){
            cout<< name[i]<<'\t'<<salary[i]<<'\n';
        }
}
```

Comment: Why mixing `cout` and `gets`? Or why using `gets` at all?

Comment: Why do you want to use `gets`? Don't use it. Ever.

Comment: This question has about 200 duplicates on SO.

Comment: If you'd used `cin` instead of `gets` you would have had no problem. `cin` can read a string correctly.

Comment: @Osiris The combination of these two is something usual; `gets` to take input and `cout` to show output.

Comment: @Broman As cwbusacker says, to fetch spaces.

Comment: @Alish NEVER use `gets` for ANY purpose. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `gets()`, I would recommend using either `std::cin >> name[i];` or `cin.getline(name[i], 30);`. The latter will fetch spaces.

You will then need a `cin.ignore();` after the `cin >> salary[i];` because of the extra return character that fills the buffer.